# Is their any way to find device is a mobile or a Tab in android ? how to remove Recent app button alone?

Tags: android

Is there any way to either remove the recent apps button in android 3.0 (I have a xoom) or clear the list? Is their any way to find device is, Mobile or Tab using java code.

Bcoz it breaks my policy app and allows people to switch device administrator if default Settings in that list. i am displaying my own launcher with out settings application.
So is their any way to disable Recent app button or to clear app thumbnail.

Please help me with any code sample or doc.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked multiple questions. Here, I'm trying to answer your second question;

> Is their any way to find device is, Mobile or Tab using java code.

You can use the screen size to determine whether your code is running on a tablet or mobile phone, see the code below;

```
public boolean isTablet() { 
    try { 
        // Compute screen size 
        DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
        float screenWidth  = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi; 
        float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi; 
        double size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + Math.pow(screenHeight, 2)); 
        // Tablet devices should have a screen size greater than 6 inches 
        return size >= 6; 
    } catch(Throwable t) { 
        Log.error(TAG_LOG, "Failed to compute screen size", t); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Source: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d6323d81f226f93f

Comment: Khan thanks for spending time for me, by using the above code i got the values like,< In Motorola xoom DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=480, height=320, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=149.82489, ydpi=149.41176} screenwidth= 3.2037401 screen Height 2.1417325 size= 3.853695455258087
 In WVGA800 emulator DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=320, height=533, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=160.0, ydpi=160.0}screenWidth= 2.0 screenHeight=3.33125 size=3.8855149265968913>. In both scenario   size >= 6; size value is not true. please let me know where i am going wrong.